# Protractor and async/await

Tags: javascript, async-await, jasmine, protractor, angular-e2e

This is my Page Object class

```
export class TopMenu {
  topbarMenu: ElementFinder;
  menuItems;
  numberofMenuItems: number;

  constructor() {
    console.log("TopMenu constructor called");
    this.setMenus();
  }

  async setMenus() {
    console.log("aaaaaaaaaa");
    this.topbarMenu = await element(by.css("ul[class*='topbar-menu']"));
    console.log("bbbbbbbbbb");
    this.menuItems = await this.topbarMenu.all(by.xpath("./li"));
    console.log("ccccccccc");
  }
}
```

this is my "it" block. This is the starting point of the program.

```
it("Click all Submenues 3", async () => {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);


    let topMenu: TopMenu = await new TopMenu();
    console.log("ddddddddddddddd");
}
```

My output is like this

```
**TopMenu constructor called
aaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbb
ddddddddddddddd
ccccccccc
```

as you can see from my above output "console.log("ddddddddddddddd")" is called BEFORE this line resolved "`this.menuItems = await this.topbarMenu.all(by.xpath("./li"));` within TopMenu class"

is it possible to omit that ?

I want to execute any line I right within "it block" AFTER my "TopMenu" gets fully created.

How to control the flow like that ?

Answer (score 2):

`await`ing a constructor, unless you're constructing a Promise (which you're not) makes no sense, since a constructor can not return a Promise (except when creating a Promise)

You'll probably want to do something like

```
export class TopMenu {
  topbarMenu: ElementFinder;
  menuItems;
  numberofMenuItems: number;
  somePromise;

  constructor() {
    console.log("TopMenu constructor called");
    this.somePromise = this.setMenus();
  }

  async setMenus() {
    console.log("aaaaaaaaaa");
    this.topbarMenu = await element(by.css("ul[class*='topbar-menu']"));
    console.log("bbbbbbbbbb");
    this.menuItems = await this.topbarMenu.all(by.xpath("./li"));
    console.log("ccccccccc");
  }
}

it("Click all Submenues 3", async () => {
    browser.waitForAngularEnabled(true);


    let topMenu: TopMenu = new TopMenu();
    await topMenu.somePromise;
    console.log("ddddddddddddddd");
}
```

Now your `it` block will await the promise returned by `setMenus`

note: based on the output you are getting, I can safely say that `element(...` is NOT asynchronous (well, it doesn't return a Promise, it may well have asynchrony, but that isn't "exposed" at all) - therefore you don't need to `await element(....`